# problems with margins in textual minipages

Tags: margins, typewriter, text-manipulation, leftmargin

[image]I'm writing a restaurant menu and i have problems with the left margins of this page, in particular in the paragraph 'Wine'. If I omit \vfill, the code overlaps the two paragraphs but it puts them with the same left margin; whereas creating vertical space with vfill it changes the second paragraph's margin. Can somebody help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,italian]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.5\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE{ \underline{SECONDI} \\
            \color{red}{\underline{MAIN COUSES}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{.015\textheight}
    Tagliata di pollo con rucola e grana \hfill{12.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Thinly cut grilled chicken with rocket salad and parmesan cheese}
    \newline
    Ossobuco alla fiorentina con patate arrosto \hfill{16.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Florence’s traditional braised veal shanks with roasted potatoes}
    \newline
    Trancio di salmone alla paprika dolce, patate fritte, pomodoro e melanzane grigliate \hfill{15.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Salmon with sweet paprika, french fries and grilled tomato and eggplant}
    \newline
    Bistecca alla Fiorentina per due persone \hfill{4.00 \euro \hspace{0.001\textwidth} all'etto}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Fiorentina Steak (40,00€ per kilogram)}
    \newline
    Tagliata di manzo con rucola e grana \hfill{16.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Thinly cut grilled steak with rocket salad and parmesan cheese}
    \newline
    Spezzatino di cinghiale e triangoli di polenta fritta \hfill{18.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Wild boar stew with fried polenta}
    \newline
    Trippa alla Fiorentina \hfill{13.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Florence’s traditional tripe}
    \newline
    Spezzatino di manzo con concentrato di melograno, noci e riso pilaf  
    \hfill{18.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Beef stew with pomegranate concentrate, nuts and white rice}
}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{.02\textheight}
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.35\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE{ \underline{CONTORNI} \\
            \color{red}{\underline{SIDE DISHES}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{.015\textheight}
    Patatine fritte* \raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{4.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{French fries*}
    \newline
    Fagioli cannellini\raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{4.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{White beans}
    \newline
    Insalata mista con pomodoro \raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{4.50 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Mixed Salad with tomatoes}
    \newline
    Patate arrosto*\raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{5.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Roasted potatoes}
    \newline
    Verdure lesse\raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{6.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Boiled Vegetables}
    \newline
    Verdure grigliate \raisebox{0ex}{\resizebox{!}{2ex}{\includegraphics{veg.jpg}}}\hfill{6.00 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Grilled Vegetables}
    \newline
    Insalatona (insalata verde, mozzarella, pomodoro, tonno, olive) \hfill{8.50 \euro}
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{Special Salad (green salad, mozzarella, tuna, olive, tomato)}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.1\textheight][b]{\textwidth}{
    COPERT0 2.00 \euro A PERSONA
    \newline
    \textcolor{red}{COVER 2.00 \euro PER PERSON}}
\end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE{ \underline{BEVANDE} \\
            \color{red}{\underline{DRINKS}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{.015\textheight}
Acqua minerale (500 ml) \hfill{1.50 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Mineral water (500 ml)}
\newline
Acqua minerale (1000 ml) \hfill{2.50 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Mineral water (1000 ml)}
\newline
Succo di Frutta (Arancia-pesca) \hfill{3.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Fruit juice (orange, peach)}
\newline
Pepsi piccola \hfill{3.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Small pepsi}
\newline
Pepsi media \hfill{4.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Medium pepsi}
\newline
Lattine (coca-fanta-sprite-schweppes-chinò) \hfill{3.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Can (coca-fanta-sprite-schweppes-chinò) }
\newline
Thè bottiglie (500 ml, pesca-limone) \hfill{3.50 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Tea bottle (500 ml, peach-lemon)}
\newline
Birra piccola (200 ml) \hfill{3.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Small draught  beer (200 ml)}
\newline
Birra media (400 ml) \hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Medium draught  beer (400 ml)}
\newline
Birra Heineken (330 ml) \hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
Birra Moretti (330 ml) \hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
Birra  Beck’s  (330 ml)\hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
Corona extra (330 ml)\hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
Tenent’s  (330 ml)\hfill{6.00 \euro}
\newline
Birra analcolica\hfill{5.00 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Nonalcoholic beer}
}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][b]{\textwidth}{
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE{ \underline{VINO} \\
            \color{red}{\underline{WINE}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{.015\textheight}
Vino della casa (Chianti, 500 ml)\hfill{7.50 \euro}
\newline
\textcolor{red}{Wine of the house (Chianti, 500 ml)}
\newline
Chianti (375 ml)\hfill{9.00 \euro}
\newline
Col di Sasso (375 ml)\hfill{10.00 \euro}
\newline
Le Rime bianco (Chardonnay \& Pinot Grigio) (375 ml)\hfill{10.00 \euro}
\newline
Rosso Montalcino (375ml)\hfill{18.00 \euro}
\newline
Pinot Rosè (750 ml) \hfill{16.00 \euro}
\newline
Prosecco Brut (750 ml)\hfill{17.00 \euro}
\newline
Le Rime bianco (Chardonnay \& Pinot Grigio) (750 ml)\hfill{18.00 \euro}
\newline
Col di Sasso (Gabernet Sauvignon \& Sangiovese) (750 ml)\hfill{18.00 \euro}
\newline
Chianti (750 ml)\hfill{16.00 \euro}
\newline
Rosso Montalcino (750 ml)\hfill{28.00 \euro}
\newline                       
Brunello Montalcino (375 ml)\hfill{28.00 \euro} 
\newline
Brunello Montalcino   (750 ml)  \hfill{48.00 \euro}
\newline
}
\end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of quite a lot of clutter in your input by eliminating unnecessary `{ }` braces.

If you want everything on the page centered, you can use the `\centering` macro.

You don't need to put the text of a `minipage` inside `{ }`. You don't really need to specify the height of the `minipage`s here either. Just let them be as tall as they want to be. You don't need to use `[t]` and `[b]` either - presumably you thought that would anchor them to the top and bottom of the page (which is not what they actually do!) but in any case the `\vfill` macro will fill up all the unused vertical space and push the second `minipage` to the bottom.

But, if you use the `tabularx` environment instead of minipages, you can also get rid of the repetitive `\hfill`s, `\euro`s, and `\newline`s and simplify the input quite a lot.

Note, the `@{}` specifications in the formatting of the `tabularx` aren't really necessary, but without them the table would be slightly narrower because by default there are left and right margins around the table. I put them in just to reproduce "exactly" what your original input was trying to do.

Note, the `\LARGE` text is now put inside a `{ }` group, to stop the large size "leaking" into the rest of the document. In the original version the `\begin(center}` and `\end{center}` (which are unnecessary after using `\centering`) did that.

I added a bit of vertical space between the English and Italian headings, which looks better IMO.

Personally I would probably have put something like `\newcommand{\UK}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}` in the preamble, and then `\UK{Mineral water (500 ml)}` instead of `\textcolor{red}{Mineral water (500 ml)` etc in the rest of the input. "Don't repeat yourself unnecessarily" is a good principle to follow.

```
\documentclass[12pt,italian]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\centering

{\LARGE{\underline{BEVANDE} \\[4pt]
        \color{red}{\underline{DRINKS}}}}

\vspace{.015\textheight}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xr<{ \euro}@{}}
Acqua minerale (500 ml)                     & 1.50 \\
\textcolor{red}{Mineral water (500 ml)} \\
Acqua minerale (1000 ml)                    & 2.50 \\
\textcolor{red}{Mineral water (1000 ml)} \\
Succo di Frutta (Arancia-pesca)             & 3.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Fruit juice (orange, peach)} \\
Pepsi piccola                               & 3.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Small pepsi} \\
Pepsi media                                 & 4.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Medium pepsi} \\
Lattine (coca-fanta-sprite-schweppes-chinò) & 3.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Can (coca-fanta-sprite-schweppes-chinò)} \\
Thè bottiglie (500 ml, pesca-limone)        & 3.50 \\
\textcolor{red}{Tea bottle (500 ml, peach-lemon)} \\
Birra piccola (200 ml)                      & 3.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Small draught  beer (200 ml)} \\
Birra media (400 ml)                        & 5.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Medium draught  beer (400 ml)} \\
Birra Heineken (330 ml)                     & 5.00 \\
Birra Moretti (330 ml)                      & 5.00 \\
Birra  Beck’s  (330 ml)                     & 5.00 \\
Corona extra (330 ml)                       & 5.00 \\
Tenent’s  (330 ml)                          & 6.00 \\
Birra analcolica                            & 5.00 \\
\textcolor{red}{Nonalcoholic beer}
\end{tabularx}

\vfill
{\LARGE{\underline{VINO} \\[4pt]
        \color{red}{\underline{WINE}}}}

\vspace{.015\textheight}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xr<{ \euro}@{}}
Vino della casa (Chianti, 500 ml)                        & 7.50 \\
\textcolor{red}{Wine of the house (Chianti, 500 ml)} \\
Chianti (375 ml)                                         & 9.00 \\
Col di Sasso (375 ml)                                    & 10.00 \\
Le Rime bianco (Chardonnay \& Pinot Grigio) (375 ml)     & 10.00 \\
Rosso Montalcino (375ml)                                 & 18.00 \\
Pinot Rosè (750 ml)                                      & 16.00 \\
Prosecco Brut (750 ml)                                   & 17.00 \\
Le Rime bianco (Chardonnay \& Pinot Grigio) (750 ml)     & 18.00 \\
Col di Sasso (Gabernet Sauvignon \& Sangiovese) (750 ml) & 18.00 \\
Chianti (750 ml)                                         & 16.00 \\
Rosso Montalcino (750 ml)                                & 28.00 \\
Brunello Montalcino (375 ml)                             & 28.00 \\
Brunello Montalcino (750 ml)                             & 48.00
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, since when I try your code I get this output:

[image: left margins are all the same]

where all the left margins are the same.

If your problem is that the left margin is larger than the right one, that is because the minipages as a whole are indented when they are on a new paragraph (and if you omit `\vfill` in your code the second minipage "Wine" is not counted as starting a new paragraph and not indented).

If that's indeed what you mean then I suggest using `\noindent` before the minipages or setting indentation to 0 in the whole document using `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in the preamble.

This is what your document looks like without indentation:

[image: menu without indentation]

Comment: You're right @TivV, but in the whole document it doesn't work as you can see from the pic that I've uploaded..

Comment: @SMoini Sorry, but we can only debug the input that you show us! We can't *guess* what was in the rest of the document and somehow know that this was not the first page unless you tell us that!